# Having only the bottom border show on a TextFormField using InputDecoration

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if it is possible to have only the bottom border show on a TextFormField preferably using the InputDecoration widget as I need to use some of the properties specific to it (hintText etc.). If this is not possible using the InputDecoration widget then a workaround to this would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far to achieve the output

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Hint',
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey
      )
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.